# How to build relations in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, relationship

I am having 3 tables:

1. **User** which consists of name, email, password, confirm_password, role as fields.
2. **Timesheet** which consists of date, time, hours_worked as fields.
3. **Attachment** consists of upload_file field. This upload_file field is used in Timesheet form.

Now how can I build relation in all scenarios, for example I want to view the upload_file of an user.

I am new to rails. Please help. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, try to think of what you want with your app in english first, and ORM later. Lets say
You want `User` to have multiple `Timesheet` and each `TimeSheet` to have one `Attachment`. So you can say

```
class User < AR::Base
  has_many :timesheets
end

class TimeSheet < AR::Base
  has_one :attachment
end
```

and your database fields need some extra parameters, `timesheets` need `user_id` and `attachments` need `timesheet_id`.

Hence I think, that you should also learn a bit about databases while learning rails, and [RTFM](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)